# how to split string characters into rows by order of appearance for each id?

Tags: sql, string, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, character

Suppose, that I have a table composed by an id column and by a string represented by a set of characters:

```
with fake_data(id, ex_character) as (
    select * from values
        ('A', 'T70891'),
        ('B', 'RT9811111')
)
```

I would like to split string characters into rows for each different id value, so expected output should look like this:

```
# id   value

# A     T
# A     7
# A     0
# A     8
# A     9
# A     1
# B     R
# B     T
# B     9
# B     8
# B     1
# B     1
# B     1
# B     1
# B     1
```

So far I've tried something similar to:

```
select fd.id, f.value 

from fake_data fd, 
lateral split_to_table(regexp_replace(trim(fd.ex_character), '.', './/0', 2), ',') f
```

But this approach hasn't worked as it retrieves pivoted column unordered.

Do you know how may I retrieve expected data in an ordered way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you swap the split to be:

```
lateral split_to_table(regexp_replace(trim(fd.ex_character), '.', '.\\0', 2), '.') f
```

it will happen correctly. to order thing you want to use `f.index`

thus:

```
with fake_data(id, ex_character) as (
    select * from values
        ('A', 'T70891'),
        ('B', 'RT9811111')
)
select 
    fd.id
    ,f.value
    ,f.index
from fake_data as fd,
lateral split_to_table(regexp_replace(trim(fd.ex_character), '.', '.\\0', 2), '.') f
order by fd.id, f.index
```

gives:

| ID | VALUE | INDEX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T | 1 |
| A | 7 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 3 |
| A | 8 | 4 |
| A | 9 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 6 |
| B | R | 1 |
| B | T | 2 |
| B | 9 | 3 |
| B | 8 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 5 |
| B | 1 | 6 |
| B | 1 | 7 |
| B | 1 | 8 |
| B | 1 | 9 |

so the selecting of `f.index` is not needed, I just included it, so you could see what was available.